# Remove row dynamically from table in templates js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which rows will be added dynamically using an add button (there is a java script function to add rows to the table on the page), these rows have to be deleted by clicking on a delete image which is a `<td>` value in one of the row `<tr>` that needs to be removed. I have done something like below, but 'onclick' is not working. The event is not getting triggered. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
function addRow(){
...
...
var deleteRow = "'deleteRowfun(\"rowNumber_"+(rowCount)+"\"); return false;'";

        var someName = "<tr id='rowNumber_" + (rowCount) + "' class = ' " + colorClass + " '><td valign='top' class='value'><label id='contactLastName_" +
            rowCount + "'>" + lastName + "</label></td>
            <td id='deleteContactAction_" + rowCount + "'>" +
            "<input type='image' src='/Projectname/plugins/folder/images/custom/delete-icon.jpg' id='contactDelete_" + rowCount + "'" +
            "title='Delete Contact' name='contactDelete' class='actionsIcon' " +
            "onclick="+ deleteRow + "/></td></tr>";


        $("#contactsTBL tbody").append(someName);
...
...

};

function deleteRowfun(itemId) {
        if (!confirm('Delete?')) {
            return false;
        }
        itemRowId = "#" + itemId
        $(itemRowId).remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `jQuery` library, I'd suggest to take advantage from it by defining `click event listeners` as follows:

```
// click handler for existing and new IMG tags
$(document).on('click', 'img', function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note that this `click event listeners` is going to be applied to every existing `img` tag and to every new one that is going to be added later.

Also note note that once we identify the clicked `img` tag (e.target) we look for the closest `tr` (row) in order to remove it

**See this [working JSfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/g7nu4nzv/)**

Answer (score 1):

I moved call to `deleteRowfun()` function into `onclick`event:

```
function addRow(){
  // calculate last biggest ID
  var rowCount = $("#contactsTBL tbody tr:last").length ? 
    parseInt($("#contactsTBL tbody tr:last").attr('id').replace('rowNumber_', '')) + 1 : 0;
  var colorClass = 'color-classs';
  var lastName = `LAST NAME #${rowCount}`;


  var someName = `
    <tr id="rowNumber_${rowCount}" class="${colorClass}">
      <td valign="top" class="value">
        <label id="contactLastName_${rowCount}">${lastName}</label>
      </td>
      <td id="deleteContactAction_${rowCount}">
        <input type="image" 
               src="/Projectname/plugins/folder/images/custom/delete-icon.jpg" 
               id="contactDelete_${rowCount}"
               title="Delete Contact" 
               name="contactDelete" 
               class="actionsIcon"
               onclick="deleteRowfun('rowNumber_${rowCount}'); return false;"/>
      </td>
    </tr>`;

    $("#contactsTBL tbody").append(someName);
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qPGa3wNm3JLf2PKfjVyL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. deleteRow doesn't exit as a function
2. when you call it it would be something like this: ...  "onclick='deleteRowfun("+itemId+")/>"; ...

Comment: when I debug the call was something like: onclick="deleteRowFun("rowNumber_3")";                                                      I have even tried using direct function name, but no improvement.